# Using GetFiles but splitting the results to show full path and just the filename

Tags: c#, linq, getfiles

I am using “GetFiles” to extract files in a specified folder as shown below:

```
Directory.GetFiles(_dirPath, File_Filter);
```

This creates a string array which is fine but now I need to do something similar but create a Tuple array where each Tuple holds the full path including filename and also just the filename. So at the moment I have this in my string

```
C:\temp\test.txt
```

The new code needs to create a Tuple where each one looks similar to this:

```
Item1 = C:\temp\test.txt
Item2 = test.txt
```

I’m guessing I could do this this with a bit of Linq but am not sure. Speed and efficiency is too much of a problem as the lists will be very small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` with LINQ which can improve performance if you don't need to consume all files. Then use the [`Path` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Tuple<string, string>[] result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_dirPath, File_Filter)
    .Select(fn => Tuple.Create( fn, Path.GetFileName(fn) ))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: What I always forget is new `EnumerateXXX` methods :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to return [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instances, which have both file name and full name:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(_dirPath);
var files = directory.GetFiles(File_Filter);

foreach(var file in files)
{
    // use file.FullName
    // use file.Name
}
```

That's much more readable than having `tuple.Item1` and `tuple.Item2`. Or at least use some anonymous type instead of tuple, if you don't need to pass this data between methods:

```
var files = from f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(_dirPath, File_Filter)
            select new {
                Name = Path.GetFileName(f),
                FullName = f
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string[] arrayOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(PathName.Text); // PathName contains the Path to your folder containing files//
string fullFilePath = "";
string fileName = "";
foreach (var file in arrayOfFiles)
{
    fullFilePath = file;
    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
}
```